# Invoke an action from container inside a List

Tags: java, codenameone

I have a form where are two List components - first one serves as a menu and it's populated on the app startup (every item in a List is a BlankContainer with Label and Button set as a Renderer) second one gets populated according to the users selection from the menu. So I thought it's possible to hook up an action to the Button in my menu, so I added new Action Event for it but the problem is that the action method (`onMenuItem_LinkButtonAction`) is never called. I did some debugging and the reason is that `rootContainerName` variable in `handleComponentAction` method is always name of the parent Form and not name of the BlankContainer.

```
if(rootContainerName.equals("Main")) {
    // "Main" is form which contains both Lists
    if("linkButton".equals(c.getName())) {
        onMain_LinkButtonAction(c, event);
        return;
     }
 }
 if(rootContainerName.equals("MenuItem")) {
     //MenuItem is my BlankContainer, programm will never pass above condition
     if("linkButton".equals(c.getName())) {
         onMenuItem_LinkButtonAction(c, event);
         return;
     }
 }
```

So is there a way how to catch such an event and get information about Button which fired the event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the button is stateless (the renderer is used as a rubber stamp) it won't work quite that way. The trick is to listen to the action performed on the List then try to detect there if the button was pressed.

If you use a `GenericListCellRenderer` (all renderers created via the GUI builder use that) you can just cast the renderer instance to `GenericListCellRenderer` then invoke `extractLastClickedComponent()` and assuming the button returned isn't null check if it matches the link button.

If not you need to bind an action listener to the link button and toggle a flag (link pressed) then in the action listener of the list if that flag was set toggle it back and perform the appropriate logic. The reasoning is that you get the button event which is stateless, the list event is the part that matters.

See http://www.codenameone.com/3/post/2013/12/deeper-in-the-renderer.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer Shai, sorry I didn't notice that article, it made it much more clearer to me :)

Comment: Maybe one additional question - I realized I will have to use MultiButton component inside my List so is there a way how to catch events from it?Because article mentions that is not possible to extract events from composite components by `extractLastClickedComponent`. Thank you

Comment: There is a multilist. Unfortunately since its a lead component extract won't work for this case http://www.codenameone.com/3/post/2014/04/leading.html Even if it did the multibutton has just one button, everything else is labels.